# Why is it difficult to delete Avast Antivirus? Is there a permission bug in windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry, virus, anti-virus

I just uninstalled avast via its own uninstaller and I realized there is some empty folders and registry record that it left. I tried to delete them with normal methods but I could'nt. so I re-installed avast and tried to delete any files that stored in avast folder and registry keys. but I still cant to modify or delete them. I searched in whole net to understand how can it possible but I can't find any basic answer that explain it. There is only way to delete it via its own uninstaller. and even it uninstalled still some registry and folders cant be deleted.

I can even delete windows os files but how can it possible to can't delete 3rd party program? Why?

And now I don't want to delete it anymore, I want to know how it can't be deleted. I tried almost all forced methods. Unlockers, taking ownership methods, safeboot, full access user, modified win ISOs etc.

Comment: Is there a permissions bug in Windows, there absolutely is not a permissions bug in Windows, the registry was designed to have empty keys.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem isn't that it has empty keys, it's that a full permission admin can't delete the empty keys...

Comment: Have you checked e.g. via Process Explorer what processes have open handles to the folders you can't delete? Typically if a file can't be deleted it is a permission problem or the file is opened by a process so it can't be deleted.

Comment: yes there is some another process but when you try to kill them you still getting permission error so it is not the main problem cause i tried it in safeboot

Answer (score 0):

Avast supplies a utility for its complete uninstall:
[avastclear](https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility).

This utility will uninstall the default Avast installation folder,
but it's possible to select any other folder.
Be careful as the content of any folder you choose will be deleted.

Comment: i already know this utility i'm asking why we can not delete without it? how a program accsess upper the administrator permissions?

Comment: Avast has a system service, so it's operating basically as part of Windows and can set permissions that you cannot undo. If you look at the permissions, you will most likely find that the owner is `TrustedInstaller`. See [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-trustedinstaller-and-why-does-it-keep-me-from-renaming-files/).

Comment: i can delete almost all system services with forcing methods but  i believe there is definitely a different situation here.

Comment: Add screenshots of the permissions of one folder or file to your post. I don't have Avast, so cannot examine it myself.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTBZm.png

im admin btw and can't save changes on this screen when i click save 'permisson denied' even in safeboot..

Comment: I'm having some difficulties understanding the text, but it's clear that the owner is *not* `TrustedInstaller`. But it seems that the "Administrators" group is the owner, and surprisingly not a single account. Avast seems to be playing some tricks here. Have you tried taking ownership of the folder? If this doesn't work, try re-doing it while running Explorer from the Start menu by right-click and selecting Run as Administrator.

Comment: i tried taking ownerships and run explorer with uac, not working..

Comment: To see if you're blocked by some installed component of Avast, try doing it while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: i tried it too. there is no running program that blocks me:) it is really weird and don't think it is happening only on my computer it is like that in every computer i tried it too.....

Comment: I've searched user-cases, and it seems that Avast does strange things to the permissions of its files and folders. Have you tried to delete the folder, or one of its files?

Comment: Look at the modules loaded into the System process with Process Explorer running elevated. In the list of .sys files in the lower pane, do you see a driver loaded by Avast? I wonder if there is still a driver loaded that is performing tamper protection.

Comment: @HelpingHand in safeboot?

Comment: No need. I just wanted to eliminate a driver being left behind preventing the deletion of certain things.

Comment: Is the Avast folder empty?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't glaringly obvious, if so forgive me. I would first open CCleaner/Tools and use the uninstaller in there which always works for me. But some programs leave bits behind. Look in your C: Windows folder for the two Program folders, 'Files' and 'Data', and carefully delete everything under the program name. Also look for folders under its provider's name, occasionally they're different but the entry in CCleaner's uninstaller shows it. Finally, run updated CCleaner 'Health Check', its registry cleanout, and the Windows drive cleaner. Sorry if you've done all that. If it doesn't/didn't help you have a more stubborn program than I've ever come across. But I do vaguely remember having to repeat it all a few times for one  of the free malware prog's, it might have been Avast ; they don't like to be dumped ! Best of luck, these things can be infuriating ! Robjn